# VBA variable passed to function is modified

Tags: vba, excel

I have passed a variable to a VBA function as an argument but have only referenced the argument in the function, not the original variable. It seems that the original variable is being modified by the function, meaning that it shares the same address space? What is happening here and how do i prevent it from happening?

Here is the function: (units, tens, hundreds and thousands are global integer variables)

```
Function Components(qty As Integer, stringSize As Integer)

If qty < stringSize Then
    units = qty

ElseIf qty >= stringSize * 100 Then
    thousands = qty \ (stringSize * 100)
    qty = qty - (thousands * stringSize * 100)
    Components qty, stringSize


ElseIf qty >= stringSize * 10 Then
    hundreds = qty \ (stringSize * 10)
    qty = qty - (hundreds * stringSize * 10)
    Components qty, stringSize

ElseIf qty >= stringSize Then
    tens = qty \ (stringSize)
    qty = qty - (tens * stringSize)
    Components qty, stringSize

End If

End Function
```

And i call it from another function using

```
Components charQty, 26
```

Where charQty = 565 when it is passed as an argument to Components and
charQty = 19 after components has completed. I determined this by printing the values immediately before and after the function call.

I am fairly new to VBA. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The parameters are implicitly [passed by reference](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vba/7363/passing-arguments-byref-or-byval/24427/byref#t=201706020439138540139) (`ByRef`) in VBA. Consider [passing them by value](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vba/7363/passing-arguments-byref-or-byval/28511/byval#t=201706020440066200781).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unlike most other languages, the default behaviour for parameters in VBA is for them to be passed `ByRef` - that means a reference to the original object/variable is passed and thus the original object/variable can be modified by the called function.

The alternative is to use `ByVal`, in which case a temporary copy of the value is passed to the called function.  Because it is temporary, any changes made are then lost when the function ends.

```
Function Components(ByVal qty As Integer, ByVal stringSize As Integer)
```

One thing to be careful of ... because an object is always referred to by a reference to the object, a temporary copy of that reference is still going to point to the original object.  So it is almost`*` as if an object is being passed `ByRef` even when you specify `ByVal`.  (`*` Except that if the Function were to perform a `Set` of that parameter to some other object, the original object would still be being pointed to outside of the Function.)

[MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264233.aspx)

Comment: Unless of course the variable being passed is an object. Then, the `ByVal` variable is just a copy of the reference variable, but it points at the *same* object. Might also be worth pointing out that most other languages default to By Value rather than By Reference.

Comment: @ThunderFrame - I have tried to include a bit about objects, but that gets very confusing very fast.  (Feel free to edit the answer if you think it needs to be changed further - I usually end up confusing people when I start getting into detailed descriptions of this sort of stuff.)